# Keras/TensorFlow - numpy vs tensor performance

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train neural networks using TensorFlow 1.12.0 and Keras API.

The setup is as follows. I have a large number of data points: each point consists of a context (call it 24 floats) and a label (1 float). The total amount of data is O(10^7) points. Test networks vary, but a fairly simple one might look like so

```
v=[keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)]
v.append(keras.layers.Dense(4,use_bias=False,activation=tf.nn.tanh)(v[-1]))
v.append(keras.layers.Dense(1,use_bias=False)(v[-1]))
model=keras.models.Model(inputs=v[0],outputs=v[-1])
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])
(...)
history=model.fit(x=train_data,y=train_labels,epochs=EPOCHS,verbose=1,batch_size=10000, shuffle=True)
```

I've been getting decent results keeping the data in numpy arrays and passing them to model.fit() as-is. However, I am not happy with the performance. It appears to bottleneck in Python code (I even tried to profile it and the Python method slice_arrays in python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py comes up as the primary bottleneck, with up to half of all time spent there.) The GPU (GeForce 1080 Ti) is in use, but its utilization (as reported by nvidia-smi) is rarely above 10-15%.

Looking for a way to speed things up, I tried to convert the data into tensors:

```
  features=tf.convert_to_tensor(train_data)
  labels=tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels)
  history=model.fit(x=features,y=labels,epochs=EPOCHS,verbose=1,steps_per_epoch=20, shuffle=True)
```

model.fit requires an argument batch_size when passed numpy arrays, but steps_per_epoch when passed tensors. Documentation isn't clear, but it seems that I should set steps_per_epoch to the number of data points divided by batch_size. This way I get comparable convergence rates. Whatever the value, GPU utilization is 100%, which is good.

But now there's a problem. With numpy arrays, run time per epoch is relatively independent of the batch size. I see 8 seconds per epoch at batch size 10k, 5 seconds at batch size 100k, and 7 seconds per epoch at batch size 1M. Convergence is generally way better if the batch size is small. So, I'd typically start with batch size 100k or less. On the other hand, with tensor input, run time per epoch goes up exponentially with steps_per_epoch. With batch size 1M (10-20 steps per epoch), I'm at 2 s / epoch, but the convergence rate is abysmal. With batch size 10k, the convergence rate is good, but the time is up to 30 s / epoch (actually slower than with numpy, despite 100% GPU utilization.)

Basically, the only scenario where tensor input actually ends up faster is the one where I don't care to use it in the first place.

What is going on and is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I don't understand, you are not happy with 7-8 seconds per epoch? That is quite fast considering that its over a million data points. Note that the model might be too small to fill the GPU, and that CPU-GPU transfer is probably your bottleneck. Have you tried training the model just on the CPU?

Comment: It's 8 second per epoch with this particular network and on this particular set, which is limited to 2 GB to avoid the tensor limit. I can easily increase the data set size 10x and make the network more complex as well, and that would get me to a minute per epoch and an hour to convergence. And then I need to try different shapes, different activation functions, etc. etc.
The CPU-GPU transfer is definitely not the bottleneck, not when I have 2 GB of data and the PCIe bandwidth is 10+ GB/s.

Comment: Not to mention that I'd (perhaps naively) expect the framework to avoid CPU-GPU transfers at all, as long as the dataset stays the same and fits in the GPU memory in its entirety.

Comment: I still don't understand, you said with numpy (I assume this means without tf.convert_to_tensor) its 7-8 seconds per epoch (which is quite good already), so where does this 2GB limit come from? We can't really help you if you do not explain your experiments right.

Comment: And more importantly, I am starting to think that your expectations might be unrealistic. Did you try training the model only on the CPU? The CPU-GPU transfer is more than just bandwidth, there is latency into launching a kernel in the GPU, for small models it might be the case that sending the data to the GPU takes more time than computing the gradients in the GPU, so its not really worth to use a GPU in that case. GPUs don't always lead to faster execution.

Comment: 2 GB is the largest dataset on which I can compare numpy vs. tensor performance directly.

With the network as described, with 17M data points and with the batch size 1M, it's 6 s/epoch (numpy.darray/GPU); 7 s/epoch (numpy.ndarray/CPU); 3 s/epoch (tensor/GPU).

Comment: I did some more profiling of the numpy case. It appears that most of the time is spent copying the entire dataset twice: first, when batches are formed in fit_loop (keras/engine/training_arrays.py); second, when, for each batch, it creates a tensor and copies the data into it. After that, the actual GPU processing is almost an afterthought. It still doesn't explain why it's _that_ slow (it shouldn't take several seconds to copy 2 GB twice), but it's a start..

Comment: This is completely compatible to what I said, one batch being copied to the GPU and gradient descent performed. This is optimized for the case where the dataset doesn't fit in RAM, which is the most common one. Also note that numpy arrays are also tensors, but not symbolic ones (like TF tensors).

Comment: And copying to the GPU is copy #3 (it comes up in the profile separately from the two I mentioned.) I guess I just had unreasonably high expectations for the  optimizations in Keras. You get interface simplicity and you pay for it with lots of waste in the implementation.

Comment: Keras is just optimized for another use case, which is not yours. Have you considered how to train in ImageNet-level datasets? Also TensorFlow doesn't have much APIs to control GPU memory allocation, so its not much that Keras can do. It works fine.