# TensorFlow "TypeError: Target data is missing" though dataset with 2 dimension tuple was supplied

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use a generator- based data set:

```
def gen():
    return zip(samples,feature)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,output_types=tf.dtypes.float32)


model.fit(ds,
          epochs=150,
          #callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
          )
model.save("/sda/anyone/imagenet-in-np/transformer")
```

whereas feature is  numpy.ndarray (2D array)
whereas feature is  numpy.ndarray (4D array)
And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Target data is missing. Your model has `loss`: BinaryCrossentropy, and therefore expects target data to be passed in `fit()`.
```

which is strange, as the target data is actually present.
Whenever I separate the dataset to two

```
def gen():
    return samples
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,output_types=tf.dtypes.float32)

def gen2():
    return feature
ds2= tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen2,output_types=tf.dtypes.float32)

model.fit(ds,ds2,
          epochs=150,
          #callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
          )
model.save("/sda/anyone/imagenet-in-np/transformer")
```

I get:

```
    raise ValueError("`y` argument is not supported when using "
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

Which means that TF doesn't accept this split.

So how should I use the generator API?

Edit #1:
I tried as mentioned:

```
def gen():
    for element in zip(samples,feature):
        yield element
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen(),output_types=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

I get
TypeError: `generator` must be a Python callable.

So I tried to swap it to :

```
def gen():
    for element in zip(samples,feature):
        yield element
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,output_types=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

I get again:

```
    TypeError: Target data is missing. Your model has `loss`: BinaryCrossentropy, and therefore expects target data to be passed in `fit()`.
python-BaseException
```

Edit #2:

I've tried the following:

```
def gen():
    for element in zip(samples,feature):
        sample=tf.convert_to_tensor(element[0], dtype=tf.float32)
        f=tf.convert_to_tensor(element[1], dtype=tf.float32)
        print(sample.shape)
        yield (sample,f)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32))



model.fit(ds,
          epochs=150
          #callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
          )
```

I get

```
2022-01-22 16:50:07.417109: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:675 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: input must be 4-dimensional[16,17,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to note here, 
how `tf.fit` works {[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for further reading} : primarily it takes two parameters `x` & `y` separately, if you set so, **like in your second case**. Else, you can input both features & target under `x` as `tf.Dataset` object. 
Use of `tf .from_generator` function {[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) for futher reading} : first of it is python generator as well, not as function. [FYI; do not use `return`, use `yield` instead] usually `tf from_generator()` uses only in the extreme cases [Ex. importing image with polygonal annotation, etc. ] and it slows down the input pipeline of the model training. 

Since here you have to just input two `numpy ndarrays`, that can easily done by using `tf. Dataset` object directly : [working example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy)

Comment: There is problem handle directly numpy array:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777753/tensorflow-keras-cant-handle-numpy-array-larger-than-gpu-memory

Comment: I've tried what you suggest in edit #1, unfortunately it didn't work. Do you have more thoughts? thanks!

Comment: could you, what is the you came across at this point?

Comment: Not much progress if to be honest. What I did is mentioned in the post. @nipun