# Is Tensorflow Dataset + FeatureColumn API slower than plain numpy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm playing with TF Dataset API and experiencing really slow times (10x slower) for training compared with plain Numpy array data.

Here is a simple example on MNIST, someone find something wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow import feature_column
import pandas as pd

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0

x_train = pd.DataFrame(x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]), columns=['f_'+str(i) for i in range(x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2])])
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x_train), y_train))
train_ds = train_ds.batch(1024)
x_test= pd.DataFrame(x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2]), columns=['f_'+str(i) for i in range(x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2])])
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x_test), y_test))
test_ds = test_ds.batch(1024)

feature_columns1 = []
for i in list(x_test.columns.values):
    feature_columns1.append(feature_column.numeric_column(i))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns1),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=6)

model.evaluate(test_ds)
```

Comment: I also noticed this difference where fitting with tfdataset was about 1.5 times slower. My guess is for small data arrays give better performance, and only as the dataset exceeds a certain size we start to see real gains with tfdataset. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931748/keras-tensorflow-numpy-vs-tensor-performance also makes similar observation.